# ¿Por qué me salta el error En desuso : la función each() está en desuso?

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con este *each* que por algún motivo me indica que hay un error:

> En desuso : la función each() está en desuso. Este mensaje se suprimirá en futuras llamadas en C:\xampp\htdocs\LibrosParaTodos\php\modificacionControlParental.php en la línea 26
> array(4) { [1]=> string(1) "3" ["value"]=> cadena(1) "3" [0]=> int(0) ["clave"]=> int(0) }

Este es el código:

```
        $id=$_POST['id'];

        $value=$_POST['checkbox'];

        $insertar= " ";

        if(is_array($_POST['checkbox'])){
            while (list($key,$value)= var_dump(each($_POST['checkbox']))){
                $insertar=mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE libroscontrol SET idGeneroLibros='$value' WHERE idUsuarios='$id'");
            }
        }   
        if($insertar){
            $alerta="<div class='alert alert-success mt-6'><i class='far fa-check-circle'></i> La configuracion fue actualizada con exito</div>";
        }else{
            $alerta="<div class='alert alert-danger mt-6'><i class='fas fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Nose se logro la actualizacion de la  configuracion de control parental</div>";       
        }
    }
}
```

No entiendo que pasa, espero que alguien pueda decirme en que me equivoco.

Comment: Prueba cambiar esa línea por: `foreach( $_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value ){`.

Answer (score 0):

Esta función ha sido declarada OBSOLETA a partir de PHP 7.2.0. Su uso está totalmente desaconsejado.

tienes alternativas  por ejemplo

```
foreach( $_POST['checkbox'] as $key => $value ){
//tu codigo
}
```

o si no quieres cambiar el codigo ya que no actualizaras la version de `php`. agrega una `@` antes de la palabra `each` lo cual es desaconsejable.

```
while (list($key,$value)= var_dump(@each($_POST['checkbox']))){
```

Comment: `var_dump()` no regresa un valor, y se asigna a un constructor de lenguaje!. Ese código simplemente no debería figurar en ninguna respuesta. Proponer usar el *operador de control de errores* en un código como ése, es como proponer esconder la basura bajo la alfombra.